# How to setup Remote Desktop Client through VPN.

Tags: networking, vpn

I am able to connect my system at office via vpn through mstsc in windows. But in ubuntu I don't know what to put in KDE Remote Desktop Cilent. All I needed to connect in windows through ciscoAnyConnect was an VPN address like omtsdd.nuata.com. And it prompts for Group name, user name and password. And in Remote desktop conection it asks for Computer name and User name and password. Is there anything else I need to make connection. I'm able to connect to vpn but I don't know what to put into Remote Desktop Connection.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I really understood your question but normally, you should only need to enter the hostname or IP address of the Computer you want to connect to in the `Computer` or `Computer Name` box and then click `connect`. The other boxes (Domain, Client Hostname...) are optional.

The box `Protocol File` allows you to put a file where you store the connection settings to make it easier next time. It is also optional.